# Automatically add class to <ul> to WYSIWYG

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Is it possible to automatically add a class to each `<ul>` element added to the CKEditor WYSIWYG?

In my project, I decided to not style `ul > li` in order to not have to rewrite CSS for each `ul` Drupal can display (i.e. menus or contextual links). So, I have only one CSS rule for my unordered lists: `ul.my_custom_class li`. I used to add a custom style in CKEditor's Styles dropdown that add this class, but it's not a perfect solution, as some administrators forget to use it (or sometimes, CKEditor does not recognize `ul` ou `a` since Drupal 8.4.x, see [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2911749)).

The perfect solution would be that, each time you add an unordered list into the WYSIWYG, instead of having `ul li`, you'd have `ul.my_custom_class li`. I know I can use an other CSS rules like `.ckeditor ul` to make it work, but I want to be able to use this specific class anywhere in the website.

I've found [some methods](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element-method-addClass) in the CKEditor docs but I don't really know where to use them on Drupal 8.

Comment: Your best bet is finding a CKEditor plugin that already does what you need and integrate it to D8's CKEditor. If your use case is too special for this approach, you'll have to provide more details on what you like to achieve. For automatic assignment of index classes e.g., I'd suggest custom text filters instead. But all wild guessing without more context.

Comment: Each time you click in the "Unordered list" button in CKEditor, a `ul > li` gets injected. What I want is `ul.my_custom_class li`.

Comment: You could add custom classes to the Styles drop down (so anytime a UL is highlighted, you can apply the class). Or you could style ULs within the designated field output too.

Comment: I don't want to use the Styles dropdown as I want my users to **only** use the `ul.my_custom_class li` and not `ul > li`. @Kevin, could you provide more details for your second approach ?

Comment: @crtlf: Shall the content editor be able to change the classes? Maybe describe what you need these classes for and why they have to be added in CKEditor. This would help to better understand what you are up to and suggest a solution.

Comment: You can use a twig file to provide an output for this field or if your theme extends classy, just add a css rule for .field-name ul {} instead of enforce a class on the UL.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I have edited my post.

Comment: Ok, understood your use case. My suggestion: Do not enforce the class in CKEditor (will be forgotten by editors anyway). Create a custom text filter that automatically adds the class to the markup when the text format is rendered. This way your content editors can just use unnumbered lists and you don't have to worry about forgotten classes.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz It seems to be the best solution, indeed. I'll try to make it work when I'll have time, and propose it as solution if it works like expected

Comment: Added a suggested answer. Not tested though, as I'm on my mobile and just copy-paste-edited something from one of my source code repos. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you want to automatically add the class to all lists within the CKEditor content for better theming.

I suggest not doing so within the CKEditor. Use a custom text filter instead. This avoids users accidentially forgetting to add the class manually and keeps your database stored contents cleaner.

The custom filter could parse the content and automatically add the classes when the text format is rendered. A good guide on getting started with creating custom text filters is this one: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8

In your process method you should use a simple DOM parser to add classes to all `ul` tags (not tested though, just for illustration):

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Filter;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult;
use Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterBase;

/**
 * Drupal 8 filter to automatically add class to unnumbered lists.
 *
 * @Filter(
 *   id = "my_lists_filter",
 *   title = @Translation("My lists filter"),
 *   description = @Translation("Automatically adds my_class to unnumbered lists."),
 *   type = \Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_MARKUP_LANGUAGE,
 * )
 */
class MyListsFilter extends FilterBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process($text, $langcode) {
    // Create DOM document.
    $dom = Html::load($text);

    // Get all UL tags.
    $lists_query = '//ul';

    // Get DOM nodes from XPath query.
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query($lists_query);
    // Whether we have results.
    if ($nodes->length > 0) {
      // Iterate over list elements and add our class.
      foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $classes = explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class'));
        $classes[] = 'my_class';
        $node->setAttribute('class', join(' ', array_unique($classes)));
      }
    }

    return new FilterProcessResult(Html::serialize($dom));
  }

}
```

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: Just for illustration. Personally, I'd use plain CSS  in my theme and omit manipulating the DOM for the beforementioned task. But if he really wants to have the classes added, the filter should do.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you ! I just had to modify the XPath query to make it work, i edited the answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Your edit doesn't seem to appear. Could you share it within the comments? - I'll happily add it to the answer for future users coming by with a similar question.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I deleted `$nodes = new \DOMXPath($dom)->query($lists_query);` and added `$query = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $query->query($lists_query);` instead. I still don't know why, but the query function does not seems to work when in one line.

Comment: I see. The original code edited yesterday had it divided into these two steps as well. I updated the answer. Thanks for sharing!